# Is there something to prepare in advance if the country where I want to travel allows me visa-free entry?

Tags: visas, airports, paperwork

The country I want to visit does not require a visa for a stay up to 30 days.
What do I need to do? Just purchase a flight ticked? Do I need other documents from the embassy or something else? Could it be that all I need is my passport and flight ticket?

Comment: It depends on the country, so it would help to know which country and your citizenship to answer accurately.  Some countries only require a departure ticket, others require you have hotel bookings or a certain amount of money with you.

Comment: My country is Morocco and I have a Moroccan passport, The country which I'm trying to go is Philippines.

Comment: The rules may have changed but I have entered the Philippines twice over 10 years ago and was not asked to provide anything. No even a fee. They just stamped my passport on entry and exit.

Answer (score 4):

All you need is a valid passport. Sometimes they require the passport to have a certain validity beyond your date of entry, but otherwise that is all.

Comment: Thats mean all I need is a valid passport and a flight ticket, right?
thanks in advance.

Comment: The short answer is that is what he means. You should also have a return or onward ticket. The long answer is that it is always *possible* that the border guard will refuse you entry; e.g., if you appear to be indigent, are on some secret watch-list, etc.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but how can they know if im indigent?
Do I need to bring me a bank document or money in hand or what exactly?
Im planning to bring my credit card with me and all the money on it, of course a return ticket and my hotel booking where im supposed to stay.

Comment: In most cases, you will be at your destination already when you go through immigration and they will ask you a few questions just to judge if you are up to no good. All you have to do is answer. They are free to let you in or reject your for pretty much any reason. So technically, even the flight ticket is not necessary besides being the means to get there. I have been to over 50 countries where I do not need a passport and never was asked any financial information and only once asked to show them my plane ticket.

Comment: @reda - In a few cases, such as Canada to USA or Bahamas to US, you will pass through immigration at departure. The process is the same though and they rarely (never in my case) ask for your plane ticket either because it is assumed that if you reach there you already checked-in and passed security.

Comment: @Itai - I have seen travelers asked to show outbound tickets, financial wherewithal and other such documents when entering visa waived countries.  Just because you did not get asked doesn't mean the OP will not.  And advising them to assume that is a disservice.

Comment: Hello, but how do i show them my financial wherewithal? do i need to provide document from my bank ?

Comment: This Is not altogether true. Some places such as USA, Australia, Turkey require not a visa but the traveller still needs to fill in an online form

Comment: @Calchas - Really? No visa but an online form? Sounds like a visa to me, or e-visa as they call it some places. Actually, I can refute your comment about the USA because I go there at least twice per year (excluding transit) and have *never* had to fill an online form. Never been to Turkey but Australia calls it an e-visa IIRC.

Comment: @reda - Usually things like financial information and employment go with a visa application because you need to acquire documents and often times even have them translated and notarized. That's why I am surprised some people say you would be asked upon entry. It has never happened to me and I don't imagine how one could get that kind of information in a suitable format on the spot at a destination airport. Maybe they are confusing it with another possibility which is *visa on arrival*. Some places give it to you there but the documents you need to bring are documented at the embassy's website.

Comment: @Itai The US requires many of us to obtain an ESTA from https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/, valid for two years, to participate in their "visa waiver program". It is not really a visa as they define it, and also you don't lose your passport for a week in some embassy somewhere.

Comment: @Itai If you look suspicious to an entry officer then they will detain you and anything useful you have (such as financial statements) can make your questioning and stay with them shorter. It is definitely a "worst case" scenario but having that evidence on paper might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

For the Philippines, you need a passport that is valid at least 6 months after your intended stay, plus a round trip or onward airline ticket.  They have no minimum financial requirement like Thailand, but do have the right to ask you about your means of support while in the country.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your answer, If I understand right, I need to have an onward airline ticket, a passport that's valid for atleast 6 months, that's all?
So if I bring with me to the airport : 
1 - onward airline ticket
2- passport valid for 6 months
3- A document that prove that I have booked a hotel where to stay during my visit
4 - minimum 1000 $ in my pocket.

So, My question is, if I bring the 4 things i mentioned above, will they allow me to travel?
I'm planning to stay only 12 or 14 days.
Thanks.

Comment: As long as you meet the passport and airline tickets rules, the airline will let you fly there.